# Is it possible to install LinqToRdf designer with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, semantic-web

The installer insist that I have Visual Studio 2005 installed. This brings me to the assumption that the project is abandoned. Is this correct?

Comment: Linq didn't even exist is VS2005, so it doesn't make sense :?

Comment: @Thomas: LINQ certainly *did* exist in VS2008, and even if you meant VS2005 there were CTPs for LINQ on top of VS2005 for a long time before VS2008 was released.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo... I fixed it afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read Andrew Matthews response [here](http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/446/is-it-possible-to-install-linqtordf-designer-with-visual-studio-2010). The project is not abandoned, but it is not flourishing either.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the [last changes](http://code.google.com/p/linqtordf/source/list) were in September 2008 - which certainly suggests it isn't under active development.

Likewise the last message on the discussion group which received a reply was in December 2008.

On the other hand, that doesn't mean the code is necessarily broken. I don't know how much has changed in terms of plugins between VS2005 and VS2010, but you might want to at least try downloading the source and building/installing it yourself.